# Foreach to access data from one array

Tags: php, api, foreach

I need some help with this case.

I have this json structure:

```
Array
(
    [_metadata] => Array
        (
            [count] => 3413
            [next] => Array
                (
                    [rel] => next
                )

            [last] => Array
                (
                    [rel] => last
                )

            [self] => Array
                (
                    [rel] => self
                )

            [shardsStatusResult] => Array
                (
                    [partialResult] => 
                )

        )

    [conversationHistoryRecords] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [info] => Array
                        (
                            [startTime] => 2021-02-25 02:57:52.451+0000
                            [startTimeL] => 1614221872451
                            [endTime] => 2021-02-25 13:39:24.013+0000
                            [endTimeL] => 1614260364013
                            [duration] => 38491562
                            [conversationId] => 847b98b7-qd87-490d-p875-43cfed34f122
                            [brandId] => 59448905
                            [latestAgentId] => 1482731814
                            [latestAgentNickname] => Marilia
                            [latestAgentFullName] => Marilia
                            [latestAgentLoginName] => Marilia

        [1] => Array
                (
                    [info] => Array
                        (
                            [startTime] => 2021-02-25 02:56:35.787+0000
                            [startTimeL] => 1614221795787
                            [endTime] => 2021-02-25 11:57:46.051+0000
                            [endTimeL] => 1614254266051
                            [duration] => 32470264
                            [conversationId] => 847b98b7-qd87-490d-p875-43cfed55f122
                            [brandId] => 59448905
                            [latestAgentId] => 1637379330
                            [latestAgentNickname] => Matheus
                            [latestAgentFullName] => Matheus
                            [latestAgentLoginName] => Matheus


        [2] => Array
                (
                    [info] => Array
                        (
                            [startTime] => 2021-02-25 02:56:18.950+0000
                            [startTimeL] => 1614221778950
                            [endTime] => 2021-02-25 02:57:37.865+0000
                            [endTimeL] => 1614221857865
                            [duration] => 78915
                            [conversationId] => 847b87b7-qd87-490d-p875-43cfed55f122
                            [brandId] => 59448905
                            [latestAgentId] => 1637379330
                            [latestAgentNickname] => Lucas
                            [latestAgentFullName] => Lucas
                            [latestAgentLoginName] => Lucas
```

I need bring data from [conversationHistoryRecords] -> [info] -> [latestAgentId] of all indices arrays ([1],[2],[3])...
I saw any cases here and some Youtube videos, but i didnt finds any way to do that.

I've tryed with this ways:

```
    foreach ($MensagensHistoricas['conversationHistoryRecords'] as $Nivel1 => $Result){
            foreach ($Result['info'] as $Nivel2 => $Result2 ) {
                print_r($Result2)
            ;}
    ;}
```

```
    foreach ($MensagensHistoricas['conversationHistoryRecords'] as $Nivel1){
                foreach($Nivel1['info'] as $Nivel2){
                    print_r($Nivel2['latestAgentId']);
            ;}
    ;}
```

But i haven't success.
Can anyone help me plx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the `info` column from each array like this:

```
$records = array_column($MensagensHistoricas['conversationHistoryRecords'], 'info');

foreach($records as $record) {
    print_r($record);
    // or
    echo $record['latestAgentId']; // etc...
}
```

If you are really only interested in the `latestAgentId` and don't need the rest then extract that as well:

```
$agentids = array_column(array_column($MensagensHistoricas['conversationHistoryRecords'], 'info'), 'latestAgentId');

foreach($agentids as $id) {
    echo $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No magic here, you just need one iteration and the right member path to access the desired property:

```
<?php
$input = [
    'conversationHistoryRecords' => [
        [
            'info' => [
                'latestAgentId' => 1482731814
            ]
        ], [
            'info' => [
                'latestAgentId' => 1637379330
            ]
        ], [
            'info' => [
                'latestAgentId' => 1637379330
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$output = [];
array_walk($input['conversationHistoryRecords'], function ($conversationHistoryRecords) use (&$output) {
    $output[] = $conversationHistoryRecords['info']['latestAgentId'];
});

print_r($output);
```

The obvious output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1482731814
    [1] => 1637379330
    [2] => 1637379330
)
```

Comment: I forgot to say, but this is for one api request, so i cant just "insert" the latestAgentId, because is 250 rows+

Comment: I fail to understand what you are trying to say with that comment. The fact that I "insert" the IDs into a new array is just for demonstration purpose. And the initial input array I use in the script the same, for demonstration purpose, it is nothing but the array you have stripped of all properties that are irrelevant here.